Should the sign of ω of a wave change upon reflection off a rigid surface?
In my physics textbook, the reflection of a wave is discussed.

A travelling wave or pulse suffers a phase change of $\pi$ on reflection at a rigid boundary and no phase change on reflection at an open boundary. To put this mathematically, let the incident travelling
wave be
$$y(x,t) = a\sin(kx- \omega t).$$
At a rigid boundary, the reflected wave is given
by
$$y'(x,t) = a\sin(kx- \omega t +\pi) = -a\sin(kx- \omega t).$$

My question is: Since the pulse is now reflected, shouldn't the equation be $y' = a \sin(kx + \omega t +\pi)$ as the pulse is now travelling in the opposite direction?

Yes, you're correct. In pretty much all sources related to wave reflection you'll see that the reflected wave goes as $(kx+\omega t)$.

Example: Pain's "Physics of Vibrations and Waves", chapter 5 section 7.

It's actually the sign of k that's changing, or, in higher dimensions, the component of the wave vector orthogonal to the reflecting surface.

The reflected wave will simply be
$$y_r = A\sin(kx+\omega t+\pi )=-A\sin(kx+\omega t), $$
as you mentioned. For reference, check Pain's "Physics of Vibrations and Waves", Chapter 5 and Section "Reflection and Transmission of Waves on a String at a Boundary".

Is it Chapter 5, Section 7 for all editions of the book? It might be better to link to the specific edition you're referring to (or at least add the chapter/section title) or, even  better, simply copy the relevant text into the post.

Corrected it with the name of the section for clarity.

The right-hand side is equal to $A\sin(-kx-\omega t)$, which is the same as original wave but with $k$ changed to $-k$. Therefore I don't quite understand the point in saying that there is a phase of $\pi$ added on reflection. I find this misleading. The wave only changes its propagation direction.

A rigid boundary (infinite impedance) also flips the sign of the wave, not only the direction of propagation. Check this experimental demonstration.. I should have used exponential notation or cosines as it clears this out. In exponential notation, $e^{-i(kx+\omega t)}e^{i\pi}=-e^{-i(kx+\omega t)} \to -\sin(kx+\omega t)$ or $-\cos(kx+\omega t)$.

I don't know what a "sign of the wave" means. We are talking here about a harmonic monochromatic wave. If you want to apply it to a soliton, you apply the reversal of $k$ to every frequency component and should get the right result. But the initial question was about the reflection of a periodic wave, not a soliton.

Re-read the question. It's about a traveling wave or pulse. The analysis using exponential waves holds equally well to pulses, but it simplifies it. You can check the reference I mentioned if you're not convinced. Explicitly (quoted from figure 5.8 from the reference):
"A pulse of arbitrary shape is reflected at an infinite impedance with a phase change of $\pi$ rad, so that the reflected pulse is the inverted and reversed shape of the initial waveform."

How do you understand this sentence? What does "with a phase change of $\pi$" mean, in equations? I have just shown you that the phase change of $\pi$ is equivalent to changing the sign of the expression within sin. What is wrong with that argument?

The reflected wave can be written as $B e^{i(kx+\omega t)}$ in general. What is stated here is that the amplitude is the same as that of the incident wave but with an added $\pi$ phase shift, so $Ae^{i(kx+\omega t +\pi)}=Ae^{i\pi}e^{i(kx+\omega t)}=-Ae^{i(kx+\omega t)}$ since $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

What you mean by the phase shift, I suppose, is that the incident and reflected waves must cancel each other at the surface to result in a node. That is of course true. But that's the phase of the oscillation at "x=0" and not the phase of the wave as a whole.

No, that's not what I mean. Explicitly, the amplitudes of the reflected ($B$) and incident ($A$) waves are related through $B/A = (Z_1-Z_2)/(Z_1+Z_2)$. If the boundary is rigid it has infinite impedance, in other words, $B/A=-1 \to B=-A=Ae^{i\pi}$. You can say that the amplitude is inverted or that it has a $\pi$ phase shift, it's equivalent. Just a different way of wording it.

This is certainly true, but it hides the fact that the wave vector is reversed upon reflection (in the case of normal incidence). If you take the real part, the minus in front is the same as the minus in front of the phase. Why should the imaginary part be preserved on reflection?

"Is inverted" and "has a $\pi$ phase shift" means the same only if the propagation directions are the same. How do you define a phase shift of two waves that propagate in different directions? The phase shift will be x-dependent. In a standing wave (resonator), the phase shift at the nodes is $\pi$ and at the maxima is 0.

The phase shift refers to the original amplitude, not to the phase difference between the two waves.
